# Git master branch as live version understanding

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-branch

So I've dealt with Git a bit over the last few days and I think I've understood the concept.. expect for one thing : How you could handle the master branch as the live version without other branches influencing it?

I'm working with a remote repository and I've 2 branches :  **master** and **development**.
Now I've tried yesterday and edited an Index file with a dummy *Lorem ipsum* text to
*You're now on the dev. branch!* And switching between those branches showed me either text via it's web address.

Now I'm trying to understand how I could work on this branch **without** affecting the live version. As if I'm trying to work on a new feature and don't want something unfinished or buggy to show live.  I'm not sure how to do this but should you then be running 2 Servers?
eg. *live.example.com* and *dev.example.com*. So creating a repository in first one, then pulling it in the second one and working on there until the feature is ready to go live via `git push` ?

**EDIT : Image for my thinking problem**

[image]

Comment: If you've both texts within the same file on both branches you made a mistake somewhere. Branches are completely isolated from each other. To have an effect on another branch you have to do this explicite with `git cherry-pick`, `git merge` or something like that. Or am I getting you wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need two separate copies of the Git repository on the server in order to be able to keep the live `master` version visible at `master.domain.com` and the `develop` version on `develop.domain.com`.

Setup virtual hosts on the server to point the subdomains to the proper locations where the separate Git repositories exist. E.g. `master.domain.com`'s document root is at `/usr/www/domain.com/master` and `develop.domain.com`'s document root is at `/usr/www/domain.com/develop`. In this case there is a copy of the same Git repository (with different checked out branches) inside each directory (`../domain.com/master` and `../domain.com/develop`).

The `master` directory is constantly at `git checkout master` and the `develop` directory is constantly at `git checkout develop` (or whichever development branch you want to be used).

There are multiple varying server software (Apache, Nginx, and so on) and each have different ways to create virtual hosts, so I will not cover the exact methods here.